# Should I edit resolv.conf?

Tags: 20.04, netplan, resolv.conf, resolvconf

I am using U20 LTS, our Search Domain changed. I did change that in netplan Config but when I grep  for old domain in /etc there is still the old one in resolv.conf.
In the file it says I shouldn't edit it. How to change it?

Comment: No, you shouldn't edit `/etc/resolv.conf` ... You should do `sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved` instead and that will update it ... `/etc/resolv.conf` is  symlinked to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` which is dynamically managed by the systemd service `systemd-resolved.service`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you change the configuration in *netplan*, use

```
$ sudo netplan try
```

to check it and

```
$ sudo netplan apply
```

to make the changes.

After that, you may have to run

```
$ systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```

to restart the *resolved* daemon. However, if there are some old configurations left in *resolved* configuration you may need to check them using:

```
$ systemd-analyze cat-config systemd/resolved.conf
```

and correct them.

Note: The `/etc/resolv.conf` file is a link to `../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` and should not be edited directly. Please, read the comments at the top of this file.